# Get two different html nodes at the same time

Tags: html, nodes, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a web page.

I want to get a dataset from two different html nodes; ".table-grosse-schrift" and "td.zentriert.no-border".

```
url<-paste0("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/serie-a/spieltag/wettbewerb/IT1/saison_id/2016/spieltag/4")

tt<-read_html(url[[x]]) %>%html_nodes(".table-grosse-schrift")%>%html_text()%>%as.matrix()
  temp1=data.frame(as.character(gsub("\r|\n|\t|\U00A0", "", tt[,])))
  temp2<-(read_html(url[[x]]) %>%html_nodes("td.zentriert.no-border") %>%  html_text() %>% data.frame())
```

The problem is that the order of the nodes of ".table-grosse-schrift" on the web page keep changing, so that I cannot match the data from the two nodes.

I found that the solution can be getting two nodes' data at the same time, like this:

```
tt<-read_html(url[[x]]) %>%html_nodes(".table-grosse-schrift")%>%html_nodes("td.zentriert.no-border")%>%html_text()%>%as.matrix()
```

But this code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to use `following-sibling` to select the **next** corresponding sibling in the pair of nodes that you need.

> The following-sibling axis indicates all the nodes that have the same
>   parent as the context node and appear after the context node in the
>   source document. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling)